# Lottery program that lets a user choose how many times they wish to play at once

Tags: python, function, loops, repeat

I'm trying to make a lottery program that can output results after a user inputs their numbers. But I want the option to allow the user to also be able to pick "how many weeks they play for", that being, how many times the program outputs results that are randomized. Basically use the numbers they inputted to play multiple games of lottery with the same numbers x amount of times they wish. I want to know how to make my function repeat based on how many times they wish to play.

Here's my incomplete  code.

```
 import random


NUMBER_OF_PICKS = 3
MINIMUM_SELECTION = 1
MAXIMUM_SELECTION = 36
MONEY_WON = 10000
OFFSETT = 4

USER = input("Please enter your name:")
print("Hi " + USER + " good luck ")
WEEKS_PLAYED = input("How many weeks do you want to play: ")



def verify(playerNumbers, winningNumbers):
    if playerNumbers == winningNumbers:
        print("Congratulations! You Win ${}!".format(MONEY_WON))
        print("Your numbers: ", playerNumbers, )
        print("The winning lottery numbers were: ", winningNumbers)

    else:

        print("Sorry, you lose...")
        print("Your numbers: ", playerNumbers)
        print("The winning lottery numbers were: ", winningNumbers)


# 'get_user_nums', gets user numbers and puts into a sorted list for x in WEEKS_PLAYED:
 def get_user_nums():
    user_nums = []
    while len(user_nums) < NUMBER_OF_PICKS:
        nums = input("Pick a number {} through {}: ".format(MINIMUM_SELECTION, MAXIMUM_SELECTION))
        try:
            nums = int(nums)
        except:
            print("Sorry your input must be an integer!")
            continue
        if MINIMUM_SELECTION <= nums <= MAXIMUM_SELECTION:
            if nums not in user_nums:
                user_nums.append(nums)
            else:
                print("Sorry, you have already inputted that number")
        else:
            print("Sorry, Your number was not in range")

    return sorted(user_nums)


# 'get_winning_nums', creates a sorted list with random nums ranging from 0-9 with a range of 3 values
def get_winning_nums():
    return sorted(random.sample(range(MINIMUM_SELECTION, MAXIMUM_SELECTION), NUMBER_OF_PICKS))


# 'menu', creates the main menu to choose game or exit program


def play_pick_n():
    user_nums = get_user_nums()
    winning_nums = get_winning_nums()
    verify(user_nums, winning_nums)


# 'main', calls the other functions
def main():
    # lottery_menu()
    while True:
        choice = input("\nPlay?: Yes or No: ")
        if choice == 'Yes':
            string = "\n[Play Pick {}]".format(NUMBER_OF_PICKS) + "selected!"
            dotted = '\n' + len(string) * "-"
   
            print(dotted, string, dotted)

            play_pick_n()
            break

        elif choice == 'No':
            print("Thanks for playing!\n")
            break

        print("Sorry, that is not a valid input. \nPlease enter either Yes or No")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: write a separate function to run your preceding code however many times you want it to be run again.

Answer (score 0):

if you ant to use the same numbers for all weeks, use:

```
user_nums = get_user_nums()

for week in range(0, WEEKS_PLAYED):
    winning_nums = get_winning_nums()
    verify(user_nums, winning_nums)
```

You might want to move the question for the number of weeks inside your `play_pick_n` function, so the player can decide per bunch of numbers who long they should run.